# How can I add 1 in the beginning of a numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array X = [[3 4 5 6] [6 5 3 3] [9 8 5 2]]

I would like to add 1 in each array like so:

X = [[1 3 4 5 6] [1 6 5 3 3] [1 9 8 5 2]]

I wanted to do it using np.ones() and np.hstack()

This is what I tried to do

```
X = [[3 4 5 6] [6 5 3 3] [9 8 5 2]]
ones = np.ones(len(X))
X = np.hstack((ones, X))
```

Comment: You want to add a (3,1) array to your (3,4) to make a (3,5).  Correct the `ones` shape.  Did you read the error message?  Take the 'number of dimensions' issue seriously?

Comment: `np.hstack((np.ones((len(X), 1), dtype=X.dtype), X))`

Comment: `np.c_[np.ones(len(X)), X]`